# Somebody who doesn't want to work but wants materials and luxury?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

What would I call somebody who, like the title says, doesn't want to work but wants luxury and items/materials?

Comment: How about: human?

Comment: Ha, not necessarily ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Freeload** - to get or ask for things (such as food, money, or a place to live) from people without paying for them (Merriam Webster)

Such a person would be called a **freeloader**

Answer (score 6):

> Entitled
>
> Believing oneself to be inherently deserving of privileges or special treatment.
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=Entitled&oq=Entitled&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

It's hard to find a word that doesn't add additional meanings.  This adds the idea of thinking it's deserved.

Comment: *Layabout* gets at it too.